# Rails - ActionMailer view: how do I link to a file in my public folder

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2, actionmailer

I want to send an email to a user with a link to download a PDF file in my public folder. How do I create the link from within an ActionMailer view? I need a solution that will work in my Test, Development, and Production environments (so, no hard coded links).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you already have a route that you use in a normal view, then you can just replace _path with _url.

If you are building a custom link, then just use the `root_url` variable in a string which will print out: http://yourhost.com/

eg for HTML emails, assuming a `filename` variable

```
<%= link_to 'Download PDF', "#{root_url}#{filename}" %>
```

for Text emails:

```
<%= "#{root_url}#{filename}" %>
```

Make sure you set your correct host name for each environment in your config/environments/ENV.rb as this is where the _url gets its hostname from

eg: config/environments/production.rb

```
config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { :host => 'yourhost.com' }
```

Comment: Yeah, I was being dumb. I didn't have the `root` directive in my `config/routes.rb`, so using `root_url` wasn't working. I thought it was an `ActionMailer` issue, but it was a me issue.